# python setup.py error while install control for python 3.9.5 using pip

Tags: python, pip, controls

Please help me. I'm trying to download control for python but instead i get this error message. Also i got deprecation message although i have downloaded the 3.9.5 version.

Here's the full logs

```
Collecting control
  Using cached control-0.9.0.tar.gz (339 kB)
Collecting numpy
  Using cached numpy-1.16.6.zip (5.1 MB)
Collecting scipy
  Using cached scipy-1.2.3.tar.gz (23.3 MB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: c:/fossee/kicad/bin/python.exe -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'c:\\users\\france~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-pqeg7h\\scipy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'c:\\users\\france~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-pqeg7h\\scipy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'c:\users\france~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-pip-egg-info-fbqezi'
         cwd: c:\users\france~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-pqeg7h\scipy\
    Complete output (27 lines):
    Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:661) -- Some packages may not be found!
    Couldn't find index page for 'numpy' (maybe misspelled?)
    Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:661) -- Some packages may not be found!
    No local packages or working download links found for numpy>=1.8.2
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "c:\users\france~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-pqeg7h\scipy\setup.py", line 492, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "c:\users\france~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-pqeg7h\scipy\setup.py", line 488, in setup_package
        setup(**metadata)
      File "c:\fossee\kicad\lib\python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 111, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "c:\fossee\kicad\lib\python2.7\site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 320, in __init__
        self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs['setup_requires'])
      File "c:\fossee\kicad\lib\python2.7\site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 377, in fetch_build_eggs
        replace_conflicting=True,
      File "c:\fossee\kicad\lib\python2.7\site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 852, in resolve
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
      File "c:\fossee\kicad\lib\python2.7\site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1124, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "c:\fossee\kicad\lib\python2.7\site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1136, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "c:\fossee\kicad\lib\python2.7\site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 445, in fetch_build_egg
        return cmd.easy_install(req)
      File "c:\fossee\kicad\lib\python2.7\site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 667, in easy_install
        raise DistutilsError(msg)
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('numpy>=1.8.2')
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: The critical part of the log seems to be `certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:661) -- Some packages may not be found!`

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with what is happening in python 2.7. Try to check your python version `python -V`
you need to switch to the new version

[Here is all the information you need, in the last comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/524552/upgraded-python-and-now-i-cant-run-yum-upgrade)